# Bash Script: want to call a function that reads input

Tags: bash, unix, arguments

I'm writing a script that calls on a function that reads for input in multiple lines. I want to pass parameters into the read, but I don't know if I can or how to.

*aka how to get enter-grades to take my values as input instead of waiting for input at the prompts?*

**Inside my bash script**

```
...
login="studentName"
echo "enter score:"
read score 
echo "comments:"
read comments
enter-grades $hw #---> calls another function (dont know definition)
#
# i want to pass parameters into enter-grades for each read
echo "$login" #---> input to enter-grade's first read
echo "$score $comments" #---> input to enter-grade's second read
echo "." #---> input to enter-grade's third read
```

**outside my bash script**

```
#calling enter-grades
> enter-grades hw2
Entering grades for assignment hw2.
Reading previous scores for hw2...
Done.
Enter grades one at a time.  End with a login of '.'
Login: [READS INPUT HERE]
Grade and comments: [READS INPUT HERE]
Login: [READS INPUT HERE]
```

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: ... I don't have the definition for `enter-grades`

Comment: You have an error in the above snippet that http://shellcheck.net will catch (the `login` assignment) and an undefined variable (in the snippet at least). Is the question here how to get `enter-grades` to take your values as input instead of waiting for input at the prompts?

Comment: yup that is the question

Comment: By the way, `enter-grades` isn't a valid POSIX function name, as dashes aren't legal (the rules are the same as for variable names, which don't allow dashes either). Bash will, as of current releases, allow this definition when using the explicit `function` keyword -- but that behavior isn't documented, and so is able to disappear without notice in future releases. If you want to be compatible with other shells, you'd be better off defining it like so: `enter_grades() {` -- no `function` keyword, either.

Comment: I was supplied that function. I have no idea what's going on in there but I'll let my supervisors know. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `enter-grades` does not read directly from the terminal, just supply the information on that program's standard input:

```
login="studentName"
read -p "enter score: " score 
read -p "comments: " comments
```

then, group your echo commands together, and pass all that into the program:

```
{
    echo "$login"
    echo "$score $comments"
    echo "."
} | enter-grades "$hw"
```

or, succinctly

```
printf "%s\n" "$login" "$score $comments" "." | enter-grades "$hw"
```

Quote **all** your variables.

Or, with a here-doc

```
enter-grades "$hw" <<END
$login
$score $comments
.
END
```